Manhattan metric proof
I would like to check my proof of the triangle inequality of the manhattan metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$
i.e: that if $d(x,y) = |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|$ then $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$.
My proof is as follows
I write both sides out:
$|x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2| \leq |x_1 - z_1| + |x_2 - z_2|  + |z_1 - y_1| + |z_2 - y_2|$ (1)
Then I split the inequality as a sum of two equations i.e: (1) = (2) + (3) where:
$|x_1 - y_1| \leq |x_1 - z_1| + |z_1 - y_1|$ (2)
and
$|x_2 - y_2| \leq |x_2 - z_2| + |z_2 - y_2|$ (3)
I then just use the triangle inequality on each of the equations (2) and (3)
And then I say if that is true for (2) and (3) and (1) = (2) + (3),
then $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$.
Have I made any errors in my reasoning?

You have assumed the consequent. Your first statement was what you are trying to prove. However, if you slightly restructure your proof, this looks good.

The idea behind your proof is fine, but you can adjust some of the wording to avoid confusion.
For instance, do not start with your equation (1); this is what you are trying to prove. Start by selecting arbitrary $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^2$; then, by definition, $d (x, y) = |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|$.
Then, you claim that you use the "triangle inequality" to bound each of the absolute value terms. However, this is potentially misleading, since the triangle inequality for the Manhattan distance on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is indeed what you are trying to show. But it's clear from your argument that you are not referring to the triangle inequality for the Manhattan distance, but rather the triangle inequality for the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$. You should explicitly note this. This justifies
$$\begin{cases}
|x_1 - y_1| \le |x_1 - z_1| + |z_1 - y_1| \\
|x_2 - y_2| \le |x_2 - z_2| + |z_2 - y_2|
\end{cases}$$
Then, you correctly add the two parts to show the desired inequality.

Thank you so much! This really helps
